# Is $\prod_{k=0}^{n} (1+\frac{1}{2^{2^k}})$ bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is obviously strictly increasing and as a result it is lower bounded by $\frac{3}{2}$,but I am not so sure about its upper bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Take the log and use $\ln(1+x)\le x$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice 
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k=0}^0 (1+q^{2^k}) &= 1 + q\\
\prod_{k=0}^1 (1+q^{2^k}) &= (1 + q)(1+q^2) = 1 + q + q^2 + q^3\\
\prod_{k=0}^2 (1+q^{2^k}) &= (1+q)(1+q^2)(1+q^4) = 1 + q + q^2 + \cdots + q^7\\
&\vdots\\
\end{align}$$
In general, for any $q \in (0,1)$, we have
$$\prod_{k=0}^n (1+q^{2^k}) = \sum_{\ell=0}^{2^{n+1}-1} q^\ell < \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty q^\ell = \frac{1}{1-q}$$
The sequence you have corresponds to $q = \frac12$ and is bounded from above by $\frac{1}{1-\frac12} = 2$.

Another way to derive this uses the identity $\displaystyle\;1 + x  = \frac{1-x^2}{1-x}$. 
We can turn the product at hand to a telescoping one.

$$\prod_{k=0}^n ( 1 + q^{2^k} ) = \prod_{k=0}^n \frac{1 - q^{2^{k+1}}}{1 - q^{2^k}}
= \frac{1 - q^{2^{n+1}}}{1 - q}$$
and for $q = \frac12$, RHS $\displaystyle\;\le \frac{1}{1-q} = 2$.